# Customizing joomla components and modules. Phoca Gallery case

Tags: joomla, components, module

Im developing a site using Joomla, and one of the requirements of the site is that it uses the Phoca Gallery Component and Module. The problems with these is tthat they have a lot of inline CSS styles, which makes them hard to customize. I've solved this removing the style attributes with jQuery, but it doesn't seem like a very good solution.

What could I do to solve this problem?

This is the site: http://aufbauzwei.flavorgroup.eu/joomla15sunprotect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update to newest Phoca Gallery, there are used mostly external CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to do it properly and get your hands dirty. Change the inline styles and add classes to each html element which you can later style via CSS. It's simple enough but time consuming, but if you want to customise the look and avoid jQuery then this is the way forward.